# Does the BigQuery CLI command "bq load" support resumable uploads?

Tags: google-bigquery

BigQuery APIs support resumable and multi-part uploads[1]. However the BigQuery documentation for the bq command line interface (CLI) tool does not mention how to use this feature or whether it is even possible[2].

So when uploading large files using the bq load tool, can I do multipart and resumable uploads?

[1] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-local#uploads

[2] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#bq_load

Answer (score 2):

No. The bq tool does not support resumable or multi-part uploads. You can either 1) use BigQuery APIs) or 2) use the gsutil tool (which supports resumable / multi-part uploads) to get your data into Google Cloud Storage, then use bq tool in Google Cloud to transfer data directly from Google Cloud Storage into BigQuery storage.